# Solution to generate reports with PHPExcel in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, caching, laravel-4, out-of-memory, phpexcel

I am having problems generating reports with PHPExcel in Laravel 4.2, the number of lines obtained from the database is very large (over 500 thousand lines), so the arrays created use a lot of PHP memory and in the generation of the final file that finishes Causing a memory overflow. I tried to use the PHPExcel cache system, but it is using a lot of system memory as well. Is there any other solution I might be using? I thought about processing the creation of the records in a partial way, for example 5 thousand lines at a time, but I do not know if the effort would solve my problem.

Code that I use to use PHPExcel cache (discISAM):

```
public function __construct() {
        $templateFileName = $this->getTemplateFileName();
        $fullPathTemplate = public_path().'/Temp/'.$templateFileName.'.xlsx';

        // $cacheMethod = \PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
        $cacheMethod = \PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_discISAM;

        $cacheSettings = array(
            // 'memoryCacheSize' => '150MB'
            'dir' => 'public/Temp/cache'
        );
        $cacheAtivo = \PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
        if (! $cacheAtivo) {
            die($cacheMethod . " Cache invalido " . EOL);
        }

        $objPhpReader = new \PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
        $this->phpExcelObject = $objPhpReader->load($fullPathTemplate);
}
```

Thank you in advance for everyone's attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [Chunk Method](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#chunk) to limit rows then for each chunk write to file. Chunk was made for this purpose

> Chunking Results
>
> If you need to process a lot (thousands) of Eloquent records, using the chunk command will allow you to do without eating all of your RAM:
>
> ```
>  User::chunk(200, function($users)
> {
>     foreach ($users as $user)
>     {
>         //
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> The first argument passed to the method is the number of records you wish to receive per "chunk". The Closure passed as the second argument will be called for each chunk that is pulled from the database.